# JTable MVC 4 - An error occured while communicating to the server

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-jtable

I have a problem using JTable and MVC 4. 
I not get my data loaded into the table and i do not understand why:
The error i get is very generic:
An error occurred while communicating to the server

Debugging the code on the server side i get the data loaded into my object but mapping it into Json to the jtable not works.

Snippet of Customer.cs class:

```
public partial class customer
{
    public customer()
    {

    }

    ...

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string CUST_NAME { get; set; }
```

Snippet of my controller class:

[Authorize]
    public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        private pcmEntities db = new pcmEntities();

```
    #region JSON Ajax based CRUD

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CustomerList()
    {
        try
        {
            List<customer> customers = db.customers.ToList();
            return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = customers }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

Snippet of my view:

```
<div id="CustomerTable" style="width: 580px; margin: auto;">Customer Table</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Prepare jtable plugin
        $('#CustomerTable').jtable({
            title: 'Customer List',
            actions: {
                listAction: '/Customer/CustomerList',
                deleteAction: '/Customer/DeleteCustomer',
                updateAction: '/Customer/UpdateCustomer',
                createAction: '/Customer/CreateCustomer'
            },
            fields: {

                CUST_NAME: {
                    title: 'Name',
                    width: '15%'
                }
            }
        });

        //Load customer list from server
        $('#CustomerTable').jtable('load');
    });

</script>
```

Someone get a solution to it?

Best regards,
Patric

Update:
I solved the problem. If anyone has the same problem, it is about circular references in serializing the Json object (EF). When u have a relation in ur model like that Parent=>Child=>Parent, JSON serialization fails. The way I solved is is to use the [ScriptIgnore(ApplyToOverrides=true)] on the attribute/s which could cause a circular reference ex:

```
[ScriptIgnore(ApplyToOverrides = true)]
public virtual ICollection<customer_documents> customer_documents { get; set; }
```

Cheers!

Comment: are you sure CustomerList should be HttpPost?  I have no knowledge of jtable, but that doesn't look right

Comment: yes JTable uses HttpPost from the documentation: http://jtable.org/Demo/PagingAndSorting, it is just annoying to get stuck and do not understand what u are making wrong

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error today.
Fix

```
 listAction: '/Customer/CustomerList',
 deleteAction: '/Customer/DeleteCustomer',
 updateAction: '/Customer/UpdateCustomer',
 createAction: '/Customer/CreateCustomer'
```

as

```
 listAction: 'Customer/CustomerList',
 deleteAction: 'Customer/DeleteCustomer',
 updateAction: 'Customer/UpdateCustomer',
 createAction: 'Customer/CreateCustomer'
```

and this should work

Comment: It really saves me from my trouble. Thank you so much.